# Fix splash screen as portlait

Tags: android, titanium, android-manifest

I have application which uses only portrait mode.

When I launch application , at first splashscreen is shown correctly, 
then just a second, it turns to landscape and back to portrait again.

I want to stop this movement and fix it to portrait all through.

My Environment,

```
Titanium 7.5.0.GA
```

Titanium produces the code for Android build and make AndroidManifest.xml as well.
So, how to show the splashscreen in Android App is black box for me.

Then, what I have tried is checking the activity and set property.

`adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -B 1 "Run #[0-9]*:"`

```
Run #1: ActivityRecord{4202cf4 u0 jp.co.myapp.castlear/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity t828}
Run #0: ActivityRecord{233eac8 u0 jp.co.myapp.castlear/.castlearActivity t828}
```

Now confirmed there are two activities `.castlearActivity` and `org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity`

then my AndroidManifest.xml is like this, is there any place I need to check???

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="jp.co.myapp.castlear" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0.9" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="castleAR" android:name="castlearApplication" android:debuggable="false" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar" android:resizeableActivity="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|density" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".castlearActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|density" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


    </application>
```

Comment: Remove this from your manifest file:  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|density"

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have tried deleting configChanges from two activities or one and many combination of elements, but in vain.

Comment: Conclusion. I don't use alloy project. however I have two Splash Screen folders `Resources/android/images` and `Platform/android/res`. If you have Splash Screens under both director, some how splash screen shown twice, and later one is not controlled by manifest shown as landscape.

Comment: So I delete Resources/android/images/*, then fixed.